# Using a Javascript argument in ruby code which lives in a script block.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, interpolation

In my Rails project, I'm firing a method onclick on some radio button elements.

The argument that is passed 'v' is the result of loop elsewhere in the code so it's unique to the radio button clicked.

I'm using a ruby helper method inside my script block which accesses a value in a YML file and I ALSO want to inject the v variable in that ruby helper method so that the unique, radio button value is referenced in the YML and it can cycle through multiple YML items.

The introduction of the v argument variable into the helper method is what I can't seem to get working.

How can this be done? I thin it's a scope issue but I don't know how to get around it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showReadMore(v){
    var readMore = '<%= t("simple_form.person.#{v}.read_more") %>';
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = readMore;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you need to access Rails functionality it has to be done on the server side. You should use Ajax to send `v` over to your server.

Comment: Can you get `v` from the DOM or is the result of some AJAX request or some even listener?

Comment: you will need to fire first ajax request to get data from yml file and then show in html.

Comment: Thanks all. I neglected to recognize the client vs server side ramifications of what I was doing.